# Intents not showing up in google actions console

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have created 5 intents in the Dialogflow console, I am not able to see any of them in the Actions console except for the Default Welcome Intent.

I am working on push notifications in google actions, so I need to be able to select one of them to be the triggering intent when the notification is triggered.

How can I see my intents in the actions console?

Currently i am getting the error : **'The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is not found**'

Comment: For those who are voting to close - the question is not too broad in the context. It references specific configuration requirements required by the Assistant environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [setting up notifications state](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#console_setup):

> At least one of the Actions in your Actions project must be configured
>   as a triggering intent which will be invoked when the user taps a
>   notification received from the Assistant.
>
> Your Actions cannot be configured to trigger the Default Welcome
>   Intent from a push notification.

If you are using Dialogflow, then you need to set additional Welcome Intents using the Dialogflow Integrations settings for the Google Assistant.

[image]

Then in the Implicit invocation section, add the Intent that needs to be the triggering intent when they acknowledge the notification. You should then select "test" to make sure the latest version of configuration is deployed.

[image]

You should then be able to go back to the Actions Console and, possibly after refreshing, selecting the triggering intent.

Comment: Thanks for the help on the Implicit Invocation stuff, after i could enable push notifications setting for the respective intent it worked as expected @prisoner

Comment: Great! If the answer helps, upvoting and/or accepting it is always appreciated.

Comment: I'm not able to see the intents even after doing this.! Could you please help me?

Comment: It may be best to post a new question then, providing as much detail, including screen shots, of your problem. This question specifically was talking about push notifications - so details like that are important.

Comment: Sure. I have added a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417523/intents-are-not-showing-up-in-google-actions-console-even-after-adding-them-to-i

Comment: Even I'm facing the same problem as @VikasNS

Comment: @Prisoner Could you please answer the above question?

Comment: Asking for an update half an hour after posting the question won't get me to answer it any faster. I'm just a developer like you and I'm not constantly on StackOverflow. And sometimes questions take a bit to research and answer.