# Intents are not showing up in Google Actions console Even after adding them to implicit invocation in Dialog Flow

Tags: dialog, actions-on-google

I have added the intent "Recent News" Under implicit invocation in Dialog Flow.
But even after doing that I'm unable to see that action in my Google actions console.

Below are the images of my Google Actions console of the project and the dialog flow Pop where I have added the intent to implicit invocation.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found what was causing the problem after some trial and error.
Basically, if an intent doesn't have a Training phrase, then that intent won't show up in the Google Actions console even though it is been added in Dialog Flow.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to duplicate the problem, so a few things to try to make sure it does show up in the console:

- On the Dialogflow Integration page, click on the "Test" button at the bottom. This forces Dialogflow to update the Action configuration.

  [image]

  This will take you to the simulator, which you don't need, but you can select the Actions navigation on the left

  [image]
- As the page says, refresh the Action Console page. Sometimes it can take a minutes or so for the Dialogflow Intent to be reflected.